# SOLID - The Interface Segregation Principle

Tags: android, interface

I am wondering how to implement Interface Segregation Principle from SOLID for the TextWatcher.

More specific: How to remove the not needed functions:

beforeTextChanged(),
afterTextChanged()

as I only need:

onTextChanged()

```
    passwordinput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            presenter.validateCredentials(emailinput.getText().toString(), passwordinput.getText().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class `NewClass` that inherits from `MyTextWatcher`
and

```
passwordinput.addTextChangedListener(new New Class() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        presenter.validateCredentials(emailinput.getText().toString(), passwordinput.getText().toString());
    }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create your own TextWatcher class by implementing TextWatcher and leave the default implementations empty. Then in your anonymous implementation only override onTextChanged().

```
class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
@Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
}
```

Usage:

```
passwordinput.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            presenter.validateCredentials(emailinput.getText().toString(), passwordinput.getText().toString());
        }

    });
```

Comment: MyTextWatcher class tells me for "extends TextWatcher": no interface expected here! You need to change "extends" to "implements"

Comment: Take a look here: https://proandroiddev.com/exploring-s-o-l-i-d-principle-in-android-a90947f57cf0 . Tried it like that but getting: setCallback(new MultiTextWatcher.TextWatcherWithInstance() --> TextWatcherWithInstance() not found